# Date formate with Node.JS, Sequelize and Moment.JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to format a date that is being loaded from the database with Sequelize.
I'm making a blog and I need to get the creation date of the article

My route:

```
app.get("/", (req,res) =>{
    Article.findAll({
        order:[
            ['id','DESC']
        ],
        limit:6
    }).then(articles =>{
        Category.findAll().then(categories =>{
            res.render("index.ejs", {articles:articles, categories:categories})
        })
    })
})
```

In my "INDEX.EJS", I'm getting,making a foreach to receive the articles:

```
        <% articles.forEach(articles => {%>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h2><%= articles.title%></h2>
                
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="card-body" >
                <%- articles.img%>
                <h5><%= articles.subtitle%></h5>
                <h5 id="displayMoment"><%= articles.createdAt%></h5>
                <a href="/<%= articles.slug%>" class="btn btn-success">Ler artigo</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    <% })%>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function()
{
  var NowMoment = moment().format('LLL');

  var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementById('displayMoment');
  eDisplayMoment.innerHTML = NowMoment;  
})();
</script>

is returning the current date, not the creation date
```

How do I pass the createdAt variable into that moment?

Comment: Like everyone else trying to do datetimezone things in JS, you need [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: I tried to use it, but I couldn't get an idea of ​​how to pass the variable I'm receiving from the database

Comment: ... what? It's JS, just pass it like you pass _everything_ in JS? Once you get the response from your db, "the db" is irrelevant, just take whatever var represents your data, and map it through momentjs.

Comment: exactly, but I don't know how to do that, unfortunately

Comment: Could you help me, please

Comment: I don't understand what you need help _with_: if you wrote the code you're showing, then you should know how to convert `articles.createdAt` using any API already, and you should probably show what you tried already so folks can comment on what you're doing wrong there. Without that: reassign `articles.createdAt = moment.whateverFunctionYouNeed(articles.createdAt, moreOptionsGoHere)` before you pass things into your templating engine. Like anyone who wrote the code you're showing would know to do...

Comment: I just edited the question, being more specific

Answer (score 0):

use

```
momentjs
```

to format date and time objects.Here is the documentation link

[Moment.js Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)